# Sorry, we're having trouble reaching the server

Tags: sharepoint-2013, peoplepicker

We have restore site from dev machine to staging. We have list in our site with people picker which is working fine on dev, but on staging it is showing message "Sorry, we're having trouble reaching the server.".

I have try to create one more people picker column in list(Stag), but new column also giving same error.

If i create new list on new column to other list(stag), it is working fine.

Can any one please help me in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are facing this issue due to SP.js file is available on NewForm.aspx page with other js files. 
There is some discrepancy while loading the page and error occurs. It is working for us when we removed the reference of SP.js file.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36583.sharepoint-2013-people-picker-error-sorry-were-having-trouble-reaching-the-server.aspx

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication https://<web adderss>
$newdomain = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPeoplePickerSearchActiveDirectoryDomain
$newdomain.DomainName ='<Domain Name like domain.com>';
$newdomain.ShortDomainName ='<net bios name (optional)>';
$newdomain.LoginName ='domain\Farm Account'
$newdomain.IsForest='false'
$webapp.PeoplePickerSettings.SearchActiveDirectoryDomains.Add($newdomain)
$webapp.update()
```

To verify

```
$webapp.PeoplePickerSettings.SearchActiveDirectoryDomains
```